# Let $f:S^1 \to X$ a continuous function $X$ a topological space. Then $f$ is homotopic to a constant iff $f$ extends to $D$.

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ a topological space, $D$ a open unitary disc on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S^1 = \partial D.$

How to show that $f: S^1 \to X$ continuous is homotopic to a constant map iff there is a continuous extension $\bar{f} : D \to X$, I mean, $\bar{f}$ is continuous and $\bar{f}|S^1 = f.$

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: Presumably, you mean $\bar f: D \to X$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I edited.

Comment: @Max, I am thinking about retracts! But nothing concrete.

Comment: Can you at least see one of the directions of implication?  In other words, can you see that having such an extension implies that $f$ is homotopic to a constant map?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, it is clear, but don't know how to show.

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi I would say that if you don't know how to show, then it isn't clear.  The answer given below is a hint in that direction.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, i think you are wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

define $H(t,x):S^1\times I \rightarrow X$ $H(t,x)=\bar f(tx)$.

suppose $f$ is homotopic to a constant consider $H:S^1\times I\rightarrow X$, $H(0,x)=c$, $H(1,x)=f$, write $$\bar f:D\rightarrow X$$ $$\bar f(x)= H(\|x\|,{x\over {\|x\|}})~~\text{if}~ x\neq 0,$$ $$\bar f(0)=c.$$

Comment: My earlier comments were wrong. This works in both directions.

Comment: thanks! It solved my problem, just as when you stated your hint it became clear. Thank you so much.

Comment: In what sense is the first line a "hint"?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, what do you mean?

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi The previous revision of this answer said "Hint: [...]" but it was in fact a complete answer. It could use a little more words, to be honest...